# Two whos in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, commas

> Recently, I just have read an article about [Jeremy England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_England), a physicist **who** has his own lab in MIT, **who** has derived a mathematical formula that he believes explains the living things.

I think it grammatically correct. But does this sentence sound good with two whos? I'm not sure because besides the repeated *who*, the first *who* supports for *a physicist*, which in its turn supports for England, and the second *who* supports directly to England. I suspect that this sentence can be shorten somehow.

Comment: I've wikified Jeremy England because this news about a possible math-based explanation of life seemed quite interesting to me.

Comment: [An article in Quanta magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20140122-a-new-physics-theory-of-life/) is really deserved to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remodel it thus:

> Recently I read an article about Jeremy England, a physicist who has his own lab at MIT **and who** has derived a mathematical formula that he believes explains the living things.

A relative clause tends to be perceived to be referring to the closest acceptable referent. I guess the reader will anyway percieve the second **who** as referring to "physicist", not directly to "Jeremy England".

Another possible way to remodel it is thus:

> Recently I read an article about Jeremy England, a physicist **with** his own lab at MIT,  **who** has derived a mathematical formula that he believes explains the living things.

I'm not sure if **with** is the best choice but my idea here it to turn the second part of the sentence into a phrase, not clause. This way, **who** will refer to Jeremy England, IMHO. At least in the text-based form. In an audio form, the listener might fail to "hear" the comma and so might lump the last two parts into one.

As an aside, I would also get rid of "just", it clashes a bit with "recently". And, per *TRomano's* suggestion below, of the Present Perfect: "recently I read", not "recently I've read".

Comment: The reordering is an improvement, but a couple of points. "at MIT" rather than "in MIT". Also, to my ear, the simple past is better than pres perf. when you have explicitly begun with "recently". *Recently I read....*. You are right to suggest "a physicist *with* his own lab at MIT, who..." in order to avoid the "who ... and who" construction.

Comment: @TRomano - thank you for the comments! I also initially dropped the Present Perfect, but then scanned Google Books and there were instances of "Recently I've read", so I returned the "have".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(Recently+I%27ve+read)%2C(Recently+I+read)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Recently%20I%20%27ve%20read%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Recently%20I%20read%29%3B%2Cc0   You may have to click the button again to rerun the search.