# Shortening multiple relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

> My husband takes care of our children who are living with him, and
> who attend school.

I want to shorten this sentence because it sounds awkward although I do not know why. Could you please give me some advice?

I used a participle below but that sounds a little awkward too.

> My husband takes care of our children living with him, who attend
> school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, you do not really need "living with him", as "my husband takes care of our children" is sufficient information to see that the children live with him.

So it should be

> My husband takes care of our children, who attend school.

If you really want to include it, then it should be

> My husband takes care of our children who live with him and attend school.

And no, it is not because of the tenses that cause the first sentence to sound odd, it is because of the use of two "who", it is recommended not to do so and better just to get rid of one of them. Look [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46738/two-whos-in-one-sentence) for more about using two "who" in one sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much! I agree although I want to emphasize the fact that the children are living with him. When you have multiple relative clauses, do the tenses of these clauses need to match? Is that why my first sentence sounds awkward?

Comment: No it is not because of the tenses, it is because you are using 2 "who's", which makes it sound repetitive and odd. check another post on using 2 "who" [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46738/two-whos-in-one-sentence) @estudent

Comment: @estudent specifically, the two "who"s can indicate two separate groups of people: those who are living with him, and those who attend school (whether or not they are living with him).